# validating an ejabberd fingerprint

Tags: ejabberd, fingerprint

I set up and tested an ejabberd-server. Ejabberd creates a SSL-Certificate itself during installation. Unfortunately I did not find any tutorial about how to get its fingerprint.

[this documentation](http://www.jabberdoc.org/app_sslkey.html) shows how to create a certificate, but not how to show its fingerprint.

I tried some commands I found. like

```
openssl pkcs8 -in /etc/ejabberd/ejabberd.pem -inform PEM -outform DER -topk8 -nocrypt | openssl sha1 -c
```

or

```
openssl rsa -in /etc/ejabberd/ejabberd.pem -pubout -outform DER | openssl SHA1 -c
```

and

```
ec2fp /etc/ejabberd/ejabberd.pem
```

When I connect to the ejabberd-server with pidgin, and select *show certificate* it shows me a SHA1 fingerprint that is different from all fingerprints I had got while testing the commands above.

I am pretty sure that this is no man-in-the-middle because this is happening in my lan-test-environment.

Can someone please tell me, what is the correct command to get the ejabberd-SSL-Certificate's fingerprint?

Answer (score 0):

SHA1:

```
openssl x509 -in /etc/ejabberd/ejabberd.pem -noout -sha1 -fingerprint
```

SHA256:

```
openssl x509 -in /etc/ejabberd/ejabberd.pem -noout -sha256 -fingerprint
```

Versions used: ejabberd 21.01, openssl 1.1.1d, Debian 10 buster.